# Python Regex Tokenize

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to use regular expressions in Python to extract out certain URLs in strings. For example, I might have 'blahblahblah (a href="example.com")'. In this case I want to extract all "example.com" links. How can I do that instead of just splitting the string?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your strings HTML? If so, do not use regex. If not, there are certainly many URI-matching regular expressions around. You might try giving one of those a shot and coming back to ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Please don't forget to leave a feedback to the responders and to upvote those answer you found useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great module called BeautifulSoup (link: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is great for parsing HTML. You should use this instead of using regex to get info from HTML. Here's an example of BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<p> some <a href="http://link.com">HTML</a> and <a href="http://second.com">another link</a></p>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> mylist = soup.find_all('a')
>>> for link in mylist:
...    print link['href']
http://link.com
http://second.com
```

Here is a link to the documentation, which is really easy to follow: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Regex are very powerful tools, but they might not be your tool in all circumstances (as other has suggested already). That said, here's a minimal example from the console that uses - as per request - regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'blahblahblah (a href="example.com") another bla <a href="subdomain.example2.net">'
>>> re.findall(r'a href="(.*?)"', s)
['example.com', 'subdomain.example2.net']
```

Focus on `r'a href="(.*?)"'`. In Englis it translates in: "find a string beginning with `a href="`, then save as a result any character until you hit the next `"`. The syntax is:

- the `()` means "save only stuff in here"
- the `.` means "any character"
- the `*` means "any number of times"
- the `?` means "non greedy" or in other terms: find the shortest string that satisfy the requirements (try without the question mark and you will see what happens).

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

*Do not use regexp:*

Here is why you should [not think at regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg) in the first place when dealing with HTML or XML (or URLs).

*If you wish to use regex anyway,*

You can find several pattern that do the job, and several way to fetch the strings you wish to find.

These patterns do the job:

`r'\(a href="(.*?)"\)'`

`r'\(a href="(.*)"\)'`

`r'\(a href="(+*)"\)'`

**1.  re.findall()**

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

```
import re
st = 'blahblahblah (a href="example.com") another bla <a href="polymer.edu">'
re.findall(r'\(a href="(+*)"\)',s)
```

**2. re.search()**

`re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`

> Scan through string looking for a location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance.

Then, go with `re.group()` through groups. For instance, using regex `r'\(a href="(.+?(.).+?)"\)'`, that is also working here, you have several enclosed groups: group 0 is a match to the whole pattern, group 1 is a match to the first enclosed sub-pattern surrounded with parenthesis, `(.+?(.).+?)`

You would use search **when looking for first occurence of pattern only**. And with your example this would be

```
>>> st = 'blahblahblah (a href="example.com") another bla (a href="polymer.edu")'
>>> m=re.search(r'\(a href="(.+?(.).+?)"\)', st)
>>> m.group(1)
'example.com'
```